# React-Navigation Drawer and Static Tab-Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

i am switching from react navigator to react-navigation and i am actually fine with this approach, but struggeling with one issue.

I want to use a drawer navigation and a bottom aligned Tab-Navigation.
This part is working as expected - no issues here.

I want to have the tabbed navigation fixed with 3 Buttons that will have the same action all over the app. ( eg. dashboard / search / favourites )

From Dashboard you can navigate one level deeper. As i am doing it now, the Label of the Tab formerly "Dashboard" changes to the Name of the navigated-to Item.

to clarify, i added a stack-navigation in the Dashboard-Screen-Tab, so the user can navigate through that pages.

How can i prevent the tabs' labes and actions to change while navigating within the tabs' stack? 
Basically i want a fixed Tab Navigation on each screen.

Should i create a fixed View-Component to achieve that?

Here is my setup:
App.js

```
        const MetaTabNavigator = TabNavigator({
        Dashboard: { 
            screen: MachineNavigator
        },
        Search: { screen: SearchScreen },
        Favourites: { screen: FavouritesScreen },
    },
        {
            tabBarPosition: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 'bottom' : 'top',
            animationEnabled: true,
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: STYLES.HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
            },
            swipeEnabled: false,
            backBehavior: 'none'

        });

    const MetaDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
        Home: {
            screen: MetaTabNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                drawer: {
                    label: 'Drawer',
                    icon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="rocket" size={24} />
                },
            },
        }
    },
        {
            contentComponent: props => <Menu {...props} />
        }
    );


    AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => MetaDrawerNavigator);
```

MachineNavigator

```
        const MachineNavigator = StackNavigator({
        Main: {
            screen: MachineOverview,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                title: "Dashboard",
                headerLeft: (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
                        <IOSIcon name="ios-menu" size={30} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ),
                headerStyle: { paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }
            })
        },
        Category: {
            screen: Category,
            navigationOptions: (props) => ({
                title: "Kategorie",
            })
        },

        ItemDetail: {
            screen: ItemDetail,
            navigationOptions: (props) => ({
                title: "Video",
            })
        }
    })

    export default MachineNavigator;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/95), you can add to the tab configuration the `tabBarLabel` property to control the label:

```
const MetaTabNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Dashboard: { 
        screen: MachineNavigator, navigationOptions: {tabBarLabel: 'Dashboard'}
    },
    ...
```